# rowsPerPageOptions in DataTable not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, primevue

I'm trying to show a rows per page dropdown selector in the `DataTable` component from `PrimeVUE`.

This is the `html` code of the `DataTable` I **have**:

```html
<DataTable :value="comunicaciones" :paginator="true" :rows="numFilas" :rowsPerPageOptions="comboFilas">
```

And this is the `data()` in **`my component`**:

```
data() {
    return {
      comunicaciones: null,
      columnas: null,
      numFilas: 10,
      comboFilas: [
        { label: "10", value: 10 },
        { label: "30", value: 30 },
        { label: "50", value: 50 }
      ]
    };
  }
```

And that generates the following `HTML` code in the **page**:

```html
<dropdown value="10" options="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" optionlabel="label" optionvalue="value"></dropdown>
```

The table works fine, as all rows are loading correctly, that dropdown is the only problem it has. Can anyone tell me how am I supposed to pass the arguments in order to show the rows per page dropdown? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
It seems that setting the comboFilas array like I have, or setting it as an arry of integers are both correct ways to configure it. Looking at the console when loading the page, this error comes up:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Dropdown> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <RowsPerPageDropdown> at node_modules/primevue/components/paginator/RowsPerPageDropdown.vue
       <DTPaginator> at node_modules/primevue/components/paginator/Paginator.vue
         <DataTable> at node_modules/primevue/components/datatable/DataTable.vue
           <UltimasComunicaciones> at src/components/UltimasComunicaciones.vue
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

It looks as it is not loading the dropdown component correctly. The relevant code of my component is the following:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable";
import Column from "primevue/column";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import Dropdown from "primevue/dropdown";

export default {
  name: "UltimasComunicaciones",
  components: {
    DataTable,
    Column,
    Button,
    Dropdown
  },
```

The imports and paths seem to be correct, so if anyone has faced this problem, I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

`rowsPerPageOptions` require array of integer values to display inside rows per page dropdown.refer [this](https://primefaces.org/primevue/#/datatable) 
for more info.

I have updated your code here :

```
data() {
    return {
      comunicaciones: null,
      columnas: null,
      numFilas: 10,
      comboFilas: [10,20,30,40,50]
    };
  }
```

Comment: It seems both your array and mine result in the same behaviour, and the problem seems to be that it is not taking the dropdown component correctly.

Comment: check what rendered in dom ?

Comment: It generates this inside the paginator block: `<dropdown value="10" options="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" optionlabel="label" optionvalue="value"></dropdown>`